# How to Filter using Regular Expression in Pig latin

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have to find a name given the first letter is 'P' and the last letter is 'l'.
In sql, we would give it as 'P%%l'.
In pig latin commands, how can this be given.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the FILTER command with a regex e.g.

```
X = FILTER A BY (name matches '\AP\w*l\b');
```

Comment: Hi Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz,

Can you please explain this query... I don understand what \AP\w*l\b mean....

Comment: That's a regular expression see for instance http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

The format of regular expressions in Pig is that supported by Java
So, use matches in FILTER:
result = FILTER input BY name matches '^P.*I$'

Answer (score 0):

The Pig equivalent of SQL's '%' is '.*'

So you can use

```
X = FILTER A BY (name matches 'P.*I');
```

Reference: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#comparison